# How to populate and use single object of the class accross a project?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a class called My_Buttons in button.py file. And I created object of the class in the same file in order to use in different files the same instance.

```
import math
from frontend.utilities.screen_info import screen_info
from frontend.env import BTN_SIZE, SUCCESS_COLOR, FAIL_COLOR, WARNING_COLOR, BTN_X_PADDING, \
    BTN_Y_PADDING
from frontend.modules.master import master, Button
from backend.ip_list import ip_list

screen_width, screen_height = screen_info()


class MyButtons:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_btn = None
        self.btns = []
        self.items = ip_list
        self.attach_all_buttons()

    def create_btn(self, item, k):
        btn = Button(
            master,
            text=item,
            bg=FAIL_COLOR,
            command=lambda: self.click_btn(k)
        )
        self.btns.append(btn)
        self.current_btn = btn

    def click_btn(self, id):
        if self.btns[id].cget('bg') == WARNING_COLOR:
            self.btns[id].config(bg=SUCCESS_COLOR)

    def update_btns(self, items):
        for i, item in zip(range(len(self.btns)), items):
            bg_color = SUCCESS_COLOR if item['is_alive'] == True else FAIL_COLOR
            self.btns[i].config(bg=bg_color)

    def configure_btn(self, col):
        master.grid_columnconfigure(col, minsize=BTN_SIZE)
        # btn.bind('<Enter>', lambda: btn.config(text='Mouse in'))
        # btn.bind('<Leave>', lambda: btn.config(text='Mouse out'))

    def attach_btn(self, row, col):
        self.current_btn.grid(
            row=row,
            column=col,
            padx=BTN_X_PADDING,
            pady=BTN_Y_PADDING,
            sticky='wens'
        )

    def attach_all_buttons(self):
        items_count = len(self.items)
        cols = math.floor(screen_width / BTN_SIZE)
        rows = math.ceil(items_count / cols)
        k = 0
        for row in range(rows):
            partial_items = self.items[row * cols:(row + 1) * cols]
            for col, item in zip(range(cols), partial_items):
                self.create_btn(item, k)
                self.attach_btn(row, col)
                self.configure_btn(col)
                k = k + 1


my_button = MyButtons()
```

monitor.py file for creating screen:

```
from frontend.modules.master import master


def prepare_monitor():
    master.mainloop()


prepare_monitor()
```

And main.py file with following code:

```
from frontend.modules.button import my_button
from frontend.client_socket import client_socket

import pickle


def start():
    print('Monitor Network')
    while True:
        data = client_socket.client_socket.recv(4096)
        client_socket.message = pickle.loads(data)
        if client_socket.message:
            my_button.update_btns(client_socket.message)
            print('Server Socket data: ', client_socket.message)
            client_socket.message = None


start()
```

In this project I want to update buttons on monitor based on backend data, and used sockets.
Firstly, run monitor.py then main.py files.

But it is appearing all imports getting copy of the my_button object. I want to use the same instance is used in all imports. I am changing this object from different places.
Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Why do you think that a copy of the object is made each time the module is imported?

Comment: Because, I want to update the object in a imported place, but it is not effecting.

Comment: How do you import the object and how do you update it? Can you please show a [mre]?

Comment: I will add some co to my question i a just minute !

Comment: Then, why my_button.update_btns(items) is not effecting ?

Comment: Why do you think that it is not effecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Firstly, run monitor.py then main.py files.

Apologies for the potentially simplistic answer, but if I understand the situation correctly, you're running two files separately. They import the same shared file, `button.py`, but the values inside this shared file seem to be copies, and mutations are not propagated between the two executions.

If that's the case, it's how Python programs work: every time you execute `python.exe`, all code is run anew. Your line `my_button = MyButtons()` was executed twice, once for `python monitor.py` and once for `python main.py`, and they created different `MyButtons` instances that share nothing between them.

If you really want them to share a value, you can use concurrency primitives like [threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html):

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

my_shared_list = [0]

def loop_1():
    while True:
        my_shared_list.pop()
        print(f"loop_1 - {my_shared_list=}")
        sleep(0.5)

def loop_2():
    while True:
        my_shared_list.append(1)
        print(f"loop_2 - {my_shared_list=}")
        sleep(0.4)

Thread(target=loop_1).start()
loop_2()

# loop_1 - my_shared_list=[]
# loop_2 - my_shared_list=[1]
# loop_2 - my_shared_list=[1, 1]
# loop_1 - my_shared_list=[1]
# loop_2 - my_shared_list=[1, 1]
# loop_1 - my_shared_list=[1]
# loop_2 - my_shared_list=[1, 1]
# loop_1 - my_shared_list=[1]
# loop_2 - my_shared_list=[1, 1]
# loop_2 - my_shared_list=[1, 1, 1]
# loop_1 - my_shared_list=[1, 1]
# ...
```

This code runs two infinite loops in one script, `loop_1` and `loop_2` (similar to your `prepare_monitor` and `start`). The first one is run in a separate thread (`Thread(target=loop_1).start()`), so now we have the main thread executing `loop_2`, and the new thread executing `loop_1`. They both access the same `my_shared_list`, with one adding and other removing values from it.